# Error linking object files

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors

I had this in my .cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "HW00.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
  string netId = "aag61";
  HW00 hw00(netId);
  hw00.printMyAnswer();

  return 0;
}
```

And I was able to compile the driver file into a .o  file without any errors

but when I run

```
g++ -o HW00.exe aag61HW00.o HW00Imp.o
```

I keep getting this confusing error:

```
"ld: warning: ignoring file HW00Imp.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): HW00Imp.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "HW00::printMyAnswer()", referenced from:

      _main in aag61HW00.o

  "HW00::HW00(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:

      _main in aag61HW00.o

  "HW00::~HW00()", referenced from:

      _main in aag61HW00.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What the linker is telling you in its usual friendly way is that your mysterious HW00 module was not compiled for the same architecture as your main. To fix this, you'll have to have all the involved objects produced for the same platform (either recompile the main of HW00 with the same options, or ask another HW00.o file properly compiled if you don't have the sources).

Comment: It sounds like you compiled your .cpp source on one PC/for one architecture (x32) ... but then tried to link your .o's on a different PC/or different architecture (x64)