# Making a connect 4 game in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Thank you for all your help. I have contacted my lecturer and am working with him for a solution. Thank you again.

<s>For a small project we need to make a connect four game. Our project is broken up into several parts with each week we are assigned a different part to work on.</s>

This week we have to make up the work on the columns by this I mean we have to use a function is called `get_column`, and use this to read a valid column number from the user where the next piece will be played.

So we were supplied the following files `connect4.h` (File used to store functions), `week8_object.o` (ignore the name its just the current week of sem), and `week8.c` which is the file I am currently editing.

So far I have the following, however when I went to check if the program works so far, I get an error in the compiler saying:

> "ld: warning: ignoring file week8_object.o, file was built for
>   unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00
>   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture
>   being linked (x86_64): week8_object.o Undefined symbols for
>   architecture x86_64:   "_main", referenced from:
>        implicit entry/start for main executable ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

The code I am using to compile is:  `gcc week8.c week8_object.o`

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "connect4.h" 

/* get_move
Prompts the user to enter a column, then checks that
 - the column is in the valid range (1-COLS)
 - that the column is not full (use function column_full to check)
If an invalid column is entered, the user is reprompted until it is valid
Returns the column number between 1 and COLS
*/

int get_move ( int board[COLS][ROWS] ){

    int col;

    printf("Please enter a column number:");
    scanf("%d",&col);

    if(col<0 && col<=COLS){
        printf("Your token has been placed");
    }
    else{
        printf("Your token has not been placed");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef CONNECT4_H
#define CONNEXT4_H 1

#define ROWS 6
#define COLS 7

// displays the board to the screen
int display_board ( int[COLS][ROWS] ) ;

// sets up the board to an empty state
int setup_board ( int[COLS][ROWS] ) ;

// Returns TRUE if the specified column in the board is completely full
// FALSE otherwise
// col should be between 1 and COLS
int column_full ( int[COLS][ROWS], int col ) ;

// prompts the user to enter a move, and checks that it is valid
// for the supplied board and board size
// Returns the column that the user has entered, once it is valid (1-COLS)
int get_move ( int[COLS][ROWS] ) ;

// adds a token of the given value (1 or 2) to the board at the
// given column (col between 1 and COLS inclusive)
// Returns 0 if successful, -1 otherwise
int add_move ( int b[COLS][ROWS], int col, int colour ) ;

// determines who (if anybody) has won.  Returns the player id of the
// winner, otherwise 0
int winner ( int[COLS][ROWS] ) ;

// determines if the board is completely full or not
int board_full ( int[COLS][ROWS] ) ;


#endif
```

I don't know how to add a object file code as I do not know how to open it. My code so far is to only print the statement to if the value the user enters in within those restrictions. I have yet to add anything to check if the column is full yet please do not mistake this. I am merely checking step by step.

Comment: 1.) add compiler command line -- 2.) add details what code your pre-made object file should contain. Possibly just a corrupted file, can't really tell from *this* description.

Comment: So the command line we were told to use to compile (  I am using mac and geany as my program to edit): gcc week8.c week8_object.o. I am not too sure what you would like me to do, would uploading the object file help?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448016/error-linking-object-files

Comment: Hmm okay thanks for the idea, I'll try and compile on my desktop.

Comment: Windows failed to work for me, attempting to try ubuntu

Comment: Would anyone know of a program that can convert a raspberry pi object file to a mac or windows format? My lecturer is being a b***h once again and not responding to my emails.

Answer (score 0):

According to a quick google search, this means your object file is in ELF format, which basically means it was built for Linux. Mac OS doesn't use ELF, so you can't link that file.

Your options are:

1. Switch to Linux for development, or
2. Get the person who created `week8_object.o` to compile a version for Mac.

Comment: Oh well that is a pain... Isn't mac a type of linux? I'll give it a shot in windows n hope for the best. Well my lecturer made the file and he is very unreliable in when it comes to email contacting... I'll let you know what the outcome on windows is. Thank you.

Comment: @sandalwood Mac is a type of unix (as is Linux (or more accurately, Linux is "unix-like")), but binary files are generally not portable between different unix variants. However, if you can get the source code (`week8_object.c`), that has a very good chance of working in both Linux and Mac.

Comment: Oh and sorry if I come out to sound lazy for not googling. I was just unsure on what to put as the search topic as the error alone had me confused.

Comment: I will attempt to try and get it.

Comment: So my windows attempt failed, the compiler in Dev C++ crashes everytime even for other projects don't know why. Is ubuntu good enough?

Comment: @sandalwood It should be. You may have to install the `build-essential` package to get all the developer tools.

Comment: Sorry for being a nuisance but the internet here is very slow and ubuntu will take a long time to download, is there any online compilers that would do the same? Or a ultra lightweight version of linux @melpomene